# Access to the profile using two different devices at the same time

Tags: laravel

I have a multi vendor website with laravel 5.7. I want my users to be able to access the system from different devices at the same time, for example through the site and through mobile.

But when a user login with two mobile devices at the same time with the same phone number (accuont) and submits a post, the second device's post is register with another number (which belongs to another system's user who is not login at that moment).

It should be noted that on both phones, the user has access to his / her profile and only logs the wrong number when submitting a post in system. I have this problem only when user connected through two mobile devices at the same time with the same number. Users can login from two site at the same time correctly.

system probably assigns a token of another user who is not logged in to second device.
I use following code for assigning token to user:

```
if ($token = $this->guard()->attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['token' => $token], 200)->header('Authorization', $token);
//            return redirect()->route('/',array('token' => $token))->with('message', 'Success')->withInput();
        }
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Are you inserting the post data into the database based on the user id or the token? I guess you would need to re-look at the way how you post and record the data in your system. Ideally, the post should be inserted/updated in your database against the user id which gets identified using a specific token.